# Android and jsonParsing using api did not work

Tags: android, json, error-handling, android-json

I am trying to do some android simple jsonParsing app using the jsonObject and jSONArray to display some data on the emulator.

But the problem is that the system force close and give an can anyone help me ????

## Log Cat

```
03-07 08:57:58.781: W/EGL_genymotion(3757): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-07 08:58:00.133: W/System.err(3757): org.json.JSONException: No value for postalCodeLookup
03-07 08:58:00.133: W/System.err(3757):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
03-07 08:58:00.133: W/System.err(3757):     at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:548)
03-07 08:58:00.133: W/System.err(3757):     at com.devleb.jsonparsingactivitydemo.JSONParserHandler.handleResponse(JSONParserHandler.java:39)
03-07 08:58:00.133: W/System.err(3757):     at com.devleb.jsonparsingactivitydemo.JSONParserHandler.handleResponse(JSONParserHandler.java:1)
03-07 08:58:00.133: W/System.err(3757):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
03-07 08:58:00.133: W/System.err(3757):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
03-07 08:58:00.133: W/System.err(3757):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
03-07 08:58:00.149: W/System.err(3757):     at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:273)
03-07 08:58:00.149: W/System.err(3757):     at com.devleb.jsonparsingactivitydemo.JsonActivityHttpClient$HTTPGetTask.doInBackground(JsonActivityHttpClient.java:43)
03-07 08:58:00.149: W/System.err(3757):     at com.devleb.jsonparsingactivitydemo.JsonActivityHttpClient$HTTPGetTask.doInBackground(JsonActivityHttpClient.java:1)
03-07 08:58:00.149: W/System.err(3757):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-07 08:58:00.149: W/System.err(3757):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-07 08:58:00.149: W/System.err(3757):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-07 08:58:00.149: W/System.err(3757):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-07 08:58:00.149: W/System.err(3757):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-07 08:58:00.149: W/System.err(3757):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

## MainActivity.java

```
package course.examples.Networking.AndroidHttpClientJSON;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button loadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        loadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        NetworkingAndroidHttpClientJSONActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

## JSONParserHandler.java

```
package com.devleb.jsonparsingactivitydemo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

public class JSONParserHandler implements ResponseHandler<List<String>> {

    private static final String PLACE_NAME_TAG = "placeName";
    private static final String LONGITUDE_TAG = "lng";
    private static final String LATITUDE_TAG = "lat";
    private static final String ADMIN_NAME_TAG = "adminCode3";
    private static final String POSTAL_CODE_TAG = "postalcode";
    private static final String POSTALCODE = "postalCodeLookup";

    @Override
    public List<String> handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        String JSONResponse = new BasicResponseHandler()
                .handleResponse(response);

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(JSONResponse)
                    .nextValue();

            JSONArray PostalCodes = jsonObject.getJSONArray(POSTALCODE);

            for (int i = 0; i < PostalCodes.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject postalCode = (JSONObject) PostalCodes.get(i);

                result.add(PLACE_NAME_TAG + ":"
                        + postalCode.get(PLACE_NAME_TAG) + "," 
                        + POSTAL_CODE_TAG + ":"
                        + postalCode.get(POSTAL_CODE_TAG)
                        + LATITUDE_TAG
                        + ":" + postalCode.get(LATITUDE_TAG) + ","
                        + LONGITUDE_TAG + ":" + postalCode.get(LONGITUDE_TAG)
                        + "," + ADMIN_NAME_TAG + ":"
                        + postalCode.get(ADMIN_NAME_TAG) + ","
                        );
            }
        } catch (JSONException E) {
            E.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

## JsonActivityHttpClient.java

```
package com.devleb.jsonparsingactivitydemo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class JsonActivityHttpClient extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new HTTPGetTask().execute();
    }

    private class HTTPGetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

        private static final String USER_NAME = "devleb";

        private static final String URL = "http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=6600&country=AT&username"
                + USER_NAME;

        AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);

            JSONParserHandler responseHandler = new JSONParserHandler();
            try {

                return mClient.execute(request, responseHandler);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (null != mClient) {

                mClient.close();

                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        JsonActivityHttpClient.this, R.layout.list_item, result));

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.json_activity_http_client, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: it is in the url  if you enter the url it will display the json

Comment: @user3006788 you are missing a `=` in your url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url should be

http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=6600&country=AT&username=devleb

The json

```
{
    "postalcodes": [ // postalcodes is the json array
        {
            "adminCode3": "70805",
            "adminName2": "Politischer Bezirk Reutte",
            "adminName3": "Breitenwang",
            "adminCode2": "708",
            "postalcode": "6600",
            "adminCode1": "07",
            "countryCode": "AT",
            "lng": 10.7333333,
            "placeName": "Breitenwang",
            "lat": 47.4833333,
            "adminName1": "Tirol"
        },
        {
            "adminCode3": "70806",
            "adminName2": "Politischer Bezirk Reutte",
            "adminName3": "Ehenbichl",
            "adminCode2": "708",
            "postalcode": "6600",
            "adminCode1": "07",
            "countryCode": "AT",
            "lng": 10.7,
            "placeName": "Ehenbichl",
            "lat": 47.4666667,
            "adminName1": "Tirol"
        },
        {
            "adminCode3": "70820",
            "adminName2": "Politischer Bezirk Reutte",
            "adminName3": "Lechaschau",
            "adminCode2": "708",
            "postalcode": "6600",
            "adminCode1": "07",
            "countryCode": "AT",
            "lng": 10.7,
            "placeName": "Lechaschau",
            "lat": 47.4833333,
            "adminName1": "Tirol"
        },
        {
            "adminCode3": "70822",
            "adminName2": "Politischer Bezirk Reutte",
            "adminName3": "Musau",
            "adminCode2": "708",
            "postalcode": "6600",
            "adminCode1": "07",
            "countryCode": "AT",
            "lng": 10.6666667,
            "placeName": "Musau",
            "lat": 47.5333333,
            "adminName1": "Tirol"
        },
        {
            "adminCode3": "70826",
            "adminName2": "Politischer Bezirk Reutte",
            "adminName3": "Pflach",
            "adminCode2": "708",
            "postalcode": "6600",
            "adminCode1": "07",
            "countryCode": "AT",
            "lng": 10.7,
            "placeName": "Oberletzen",
            "lat": 47.5166667,
            "adminName1": "Tirol"
        },
        {
            "adminCode3": "70827",
            "adminName2": "Politischer Bezirk Reutte",
            "adminName3": "Pinswang",
            "adminCode2": "708",
            "postalcode": "6600",
            "adminCode1": "07",
            "countryCode": "AT",
            "lng": 10.6833333,
            "placeName": "Oberpinswang",
            "lat": 47.5333333,
            "adminName1": "Tirol"
        },
        {
            "adminCode3": "70826",
            "adminName2": "Politischer Bezirk Reutte",
            "adminName3": "Pflach",
            "adminCode2": "708",
            "postalcode": "6600",
            "adminCode1": "07",
            "countryCode": "AT",
            "lng": 10.7166667,
            "placeName": "Pflach",
            "lat": 47.5166667,
            "adminName1": "Tirol"
        },
        {
            "adminCode3": "70827",
            "adminName2": "Politischer Bezirk Reutte",
            "adminName3": "Pinswang",
            "adminCode2": "708",
            "postalcode": "6600",
            "adminCode1": "07",
            "countryCode": "AT",
            "lng": 10.6666667,
            "placeName": "Pinswang",
            "lat": 47.5333333,
            "adminName1": "Tirol"
        },
        {
            "adminCode3": "70828",
            "adminName2": "Politischer Bezirk Reutte",
            "adminName3": "Reutte",
            "adminCode2": "708",
            "postalcode": "6600",
            "adminCode1": "07",
            "countryCode": "AT",
            "lng": 10.7166667,
            "placeName": "Reutte",
            "lat": 47.4833333,
            "adminName1": "Tirol"
        },
        {
            "adminCode3": "70826",
            "adminName2": "Politischer Bezirk Reutte",
            "adminName3": "Pflach",
            "adminCode2": "708",
            "postalcode": "6600",
            "adminCode1": "07",
            "countryCode": "AT",
            "lng": 10.7,
            "placeName": "Unterletzen",
            "lat": 47.5166667,
            "adminName1": "Tirol"
        },
        {
            "adminCode3": "70827",
            "adminName2": "Politischer Bezirk Reutte",
            "adminName3": "Pinswang",
            "adminCode2": "708",
            "postalcode": "6600",
            "adminCode1": "07",
            "countryCode": "AT",
            "lng": 10.6666667,
            "placeName": "Unterpinswang",
            "lat": 47.5333333,
            "adminName1": "Tirol"
        }
    ]
}
```

> org.json.JSONException: No value for postalCodeLookup

Also you have

```
private static final String POSTALCODE = "postalCodeLookup"
```

Then

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(JSONResponse)
                .nextValue();

JSONArray PostalCodes = jsonObject.getJSONArray(POSTALCODE);
```

It should be

```
private static final String POSTALCODE = "postalcodes"
JSONArray PostalCodes = jsonObject.getJSONArray(POSTALCODE);
```

Comment: @user3006788 your are welcome. glad my suggestion works

Comment: @ Raghunandan now if i want to display and categorized these data in fields how to do it ?? like table or text view mean each value will be displayed in a  specific field

Comment: @user3006788 USE LSITVIEW WITH TEXTVIEWS.  new problem ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

try to change your url to:

> private static final String URL = "http://api.geonames.org/postalCodeLookupJSON?postalcode=6600&country=AT&username="
>                   + USER_NAME;

I guess ur missing out "="

Comment: i added "=" and changed the username to "devleb" it is my account and still did not work

Comment: I cannot find any POSTALCODE = "postalCodeLookup" in the json response. Try
JSONArray PostalCodes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("postalcodes");

Comment: Please check your constants, POSTALCODE should be "postalcodes" and not "postalCodeLookup" as per the response.